# Reading empty string from CSV file in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, awk, csv

I'm using the following `gawk` script to read values from the first column of the csv file file.csv.
 I use `gawk` since I don't want any embedded commas to be ignored.

```
col=`gawk ' 
BEGIN {
FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
{print $1 }' file.csv`
```

For example, file.csv is:

```
col1,col2
"a,a","a,a1"
,"b1"
"c","c1"
```

The problem is that since the second row of the first column is empty, when it reads the values from the first column it takes the value of the second column as the value of the second row.

```
echo $col
```

returns

```
a,a
b1
c
```

but I would like it to acknowledge the empty string as follows:

```
a,a

c
```

How could I achieve such behaviour?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE:** 
I noticed that if the empty string/space is in the last row, this method ignores it.

```
col=`gawk ' 
BEGIN {
FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")+"
}
{print $1 }' file.csv`
```

For example, if the file.csv is the following:

```
col1,col2
"a,a","a,a1" 
"b","b1" 
,"c1"
```

The result would be

```
col1
a,a
b
```

instad of

```
col1
a,a
b
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: The awk script will do what you asked for. It's how you're storing it's output in `col` that's causing your problem (try `printf 'foo\nbar\n\n'` then `col=$(printf 'foo\nbar\n\n'); echo "$col"` to see what I mean) but that would be a different question.

Comment: What would be an appropriate way to store the output to keep that empty string in the last column then?

Comment: See [my answer to your followup question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/662643/133219) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `+`s (1 or more repetitions) to `*`s (0 or more repetitions) in your `FPAT` so it allows for empty fields:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")+" }
{ print $1 }
' file.csv
col1
"a,a"

"c"
```

I also added a final `+` so it'll allow for escaped (doubled) quotes in your quoted fields, e.g. `"foo""bar"`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk for more info on parsing CSVs with awk even if the fields include newlines.

---

As mentioned in the comments, that will work in gawk 5.1.0 and later but you may have trouble using the above with gawk 4.1.4 due to 2 bugs related to `FPAT` processing:

1. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-04/msg00000.html
2. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-11/msg00000.html

If so, you can work around the bugs by either:

1. Just referencing `NF` at the start of the script, e.g. by adding `{ NF }` as the first line, should be all you need but if that doesn't work then
2. By clearing then re-assigning `FPAT` at the start of the script, e.g. by adding `{ oFPAT=FPAT; FPAT=""; FPAT=oFPAT }` as the first line.

Comment: Seems to work in *GNU Awk 5.1.0* but not in *GNU Awk 4.1.4* apparently...

Comment: @steeldriver gawk 4.1.4 had 2 bug2 related to FPAT, I've updated my answer to include workarounds for them.

Comment: Wow gnarly -  thanks. I couldn't get the `NF` trick to work but can confirm that the `oFPAT=FPAT;FPAT="";FPAT=oFPAT` one did

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure which bug you were hitting, nor whether referencing `NF` worked around both of them - glad I had a solution handy!

Comment: Thank you Ed. I don't know if I should create a new question for this but perhaps you could help me with this.
Would you happen to know how to place the values from the first column, including that empty string, into an array?
Something as such: `arr=("a,a"   ""   "c")`
I tried `IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a arr <<<"$col"` but it seems to ignore the empty string.

Comment: You're welcome. You should ask a new question as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged and make sure when talking about variables and arrays you say "shell array" or "awk array" so it's clear which you mean. It's also extremely unlikely that using a shell array for whatever you have in mind instead of just doing all the processing in awk is the best approach so make sure your question is clear on what it is you're trying to do (not just how you're trying to do it).

Comment: I noticed that if the empty string/space is in the last row, this method ignores it. For example, if the file.csv is the following: 
`col1,col2
"a,a","a,a1"
"b","b1"
,"c1"`
The result would be 
`col1
"a,a"
"b"`
instad of
`col1
"a,a"
"b"
      `
What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: No, the method I posted does not ignore anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ',"' 'NR>1{gsub(/\"/,"",$1);print $1}' filename
```

output

```
a,a

c
```